# Single Outgoing Call + Conference Call

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

How to implement a single outgoing call and conference call?

I have outgoing call setup working: A POST request hits the `/voice` endpoint and call goes through, likewise incoming call. I have read the conference code sample and see it hits the same `/voice` endpoint.

My logic is implementing a system that states whether outgoing call is single or conference then the option gets triggered in an if-else statement.

Pseudocode, kinda:

```
@app.route('/voice', methods=['POST'])
def voice():
    option = flask.request.get_json()['option']
    if option == 'single':
        #outgoing_call code
    else:
        #conference_call code
```

my `{{domain}}/voice` is registered on TWIML app.

Is there a good/better approach on getting this done or am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the outbound call, you provide the URL to the `/voice` endpoint on your server. If you know at the time that you are either making a single or conference call, you can provide different URLs that do different things when the call connects. For example:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Dial

@app.route("/conference", methods=["POST"])
def conference():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    dial = Dial()
    dial.conference("Conference")
    response.append(dial)
    return Response(str(response), mimetype="text/xml")

@app.route("/voice", methods=["POST"])
def single():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    dial = Dial()
    dial.number("+123456789")
    response.append(dial)
    return Response(str(response), mimetype="text/xml")
```

Then, when you create the call, use a different endpoint based on what you want to happen:

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

if (SINGLE_CALL_CONDITIONAL):
    url = "https://example.com/voice
else:
    url = "https://example.com/conference"

call = client.calls.create(
                        url=url,
                        to='+14155551212',
                        from_='+15017122661'
                    )
```

Comment: This is quite insightful, @philnash.

My issue now would be figuring out how to include both ```/voice``` and ```/conference``` on my TWIML app, which only has one HTTP POST tab for Voice.

I'm going to code it out, if it pans out I'll gladly mark your response as the accepted answer.

Comment: The TwiML app is used for inbound. For outbound you set the URL in the API call, as above.